# How does collabedit work?

Tags: session, web

When you enter the Collabedit online editor it gives you a url with a random session name so you can send to friends to join. How does that work?
How does the session name get created and added to the URL .i.e the y3y2c part
in http://collabedit.com/y3y2c

If there is any tutorials you can link, please do.
Thanks.